# Access Denied on Sharepoint provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am deploying sharepoint hosted app on my sharepoint online environment. Everything was working fine till yesterday. When I click on the app, access dedined page is shown.
Even if I create new app and install it, still I get the same error.